# Rails 3: Generate Fake Data to Populate DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rspec2

I am using faker to generate sample data. I have this as follows:

```
require 'faker'

namespace :db do 
  desc "Fill database with sample data" 
  task :populate => :environment do
    Rake::Task['db:reset'].invoke 
    User.create!(:name => "rails",
    :email => "example@railstutorial.org", 
    :password => "foobar", 
    :password_confirmation => "foobar")

    99.times do |n| 
      #name = Faker::Name.name
      name = "rails#{n+1}"
      email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org" 
      password = "password" 
      user = User.create!(:name => name,
      :email => email, 
      :password => password, 
      :password_confirmation => password)

    end 
  end
end
```

The problem is that I have a couple of after_save callbacks that are not being called when the User is created. Why is that? Thanks

The methods:

```
  after_save :create_profile
def create_profile
    self.build_profile()
  end
```

Comment: Recommend you post the after_save callback portion in the model (both the method and the callback)

Comment: Did you tried to, instead of use a trigger, overwrite the save method? I am new to rails, so I don't know if it is a anti-pattern practice... :)

Comment: @JEsse, I've added them.

Comment: Does before_save get triggered? Or other callbacks?

Answer (score -2):

In all my reading, it seems that `save!` bypasses any custom `before_save`, `on_save` or `after_save` filters you have defined. The source code for `create!` reveals that it invokes `save!`. Unless you absolutely NEED the bang version, why are you using it? Try removing all your bang methods and just invoking the non-bang versions:

```
[1..100].each do |n| 
  name = "rails#{n+1}"
  email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org" 
  password = "password" 
  user = User.new(:name => name, :email => email, :password => password, :password_confirmation => password)

  if !user.save
    puts "There was an error while making #{user.inspect}"
  end
end
```